# Make fails on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, poco

I'm trying to make my project using Makefile. The Makefile works correctly for other Mac's but bring error in my case.

The output is as follows:

```
CC  kernel.cpp
In file included from kernel.cpp:13:
In file included from ./kernel.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/JSON/Object.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/JSON/Array.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/Dynamic/Var.h:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/Dynamic/VarHolder.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/NumberFormatter.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/NumericString.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/FPEnvironment.h:35:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/FPEnvironment_C99.h:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: 
      no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: 
      no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:315:9: error: 
      no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:757:12: note: 
      'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __M...
           ^
In file included from kernel.cpp:13:
In file included from ./kernel.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/JSON/Object.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/JSON/Array.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/Dynamic/Var.h:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/Dynamic/VarHolder.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/NumberFormatter.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/NumericString.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/FPEnvironment.h:35:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/FPEnvironment_C99.h:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:316:9: error: 
      no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: 
      no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace
using ::isnan;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: 
      no member named 'isnormal' in the global namespace
using ::isnormal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:319:7: error: 
      no member named 'isgreater' in the global namespace; did you mean
      '::std::greater'?
using ::isgreater;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:718:29: note: 
      '::std::greater' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from kernel.cpp:13:
In file included from ./kernel.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/JSON/Object.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/JSON/Array.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/Dynamic/Var.h:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/Dynamic/VarHolder.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/NumberFormatter.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/NumericString.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/FPEnvironment.h:35:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Poco/FPEnvironment_C99.h:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:320:7: error: 
      no member named 'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace; did you mean
      '::std::greater_equal'?
using ::isgreaterequal;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:747:29: note: 
      '::std::greater_equal' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater_equal : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
```

The makefile has been tested on Linux platforms, and it's works correctly.
Any recommendations, whats wrong in my Mac c++ configs ?

I'm using MacOS High Sierra(10.13), and Xcode v9.0.1

---

***Edited***

This is compiling command:

```
gcc -pipe -x c++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -pedantic -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wundef -Wfloat-equal -Werror -Wconversion -DPROJECT_VERSION="0.0.1" -DUSE_SDK="no"  -g -g3 -ggdb3 -D__i386__=1 -D__ppc64__=0 -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-conversion -Wno-float-equal -Wno-unused-parameter -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/c++/version -I/git/p2p/inc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/c++/version  src/kernel.cpp -o /git/p2p/obj/kernel.o
```

Comment: You need to compile in C++11 mode.

Comment: How can I do that ?@molbdnilo

Comment: I have just checked, it's compiling in C++11 mode @molbdnilo

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Ssswift this is the output of gcc --version : : : `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
`

Comment: The problem has been solved by just renaming math.h file in

    `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/math.h`

Now it's uses this math.h

    `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h`

Comment: There are some updates for this question at http://thetechawesomeness.ideasmatter.info/configuring-alternative-compilers-in-macos.html with test for macOS 10.15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of running `gcc -x c++` I recommend you run `g++` or, better on MacOS, `clang++`.

Also, your compile line appears to be missing the `-c` option which would tell the compiler to generate an object file; without that it will try to link your file and create an executable.

Also I find it very strange that you have added `-D__i386__` and `-D__ppc64__` to your compile line: those are typically system macros that are defined by your operating system, not provided on the command line of the compiler.

Another potential problem is why you are explicitly adding system header file directories to your compile line with `-I`.  The compiler will add those itself, and using the proper configuration.  System headers often require extra care to include in the correct order etc.

If you change to the proper directory and run this from your shell prompt:

```
clang++ -pipe -std=c++11 -fPIC -pedantic -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings \
  -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wendif-labels \
  -Wundef -Wfloat-equal -Werror -Wconversion -DPROJECT_VERSION="0.0.1" \
  -DUSE_SDK="no"  -g -g3 -ggdb3 -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-conversion \
  -Wno-float-equal -Wno-unused-parameter -I/usr/local/include \
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/git/p2p/inc \
  -c -o /git/p2p/obj/kernel.o  src/kernel.cpp
```

does it compile properly?

Comment: The problem has been solved by just renaming math.h file in

    `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/math.h`
Now it's uses this math.h

    `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h`

Comment: You should *never* rename system header files!  That's insanity.  When you install a new Xcode update it will break again; if you try it on a different system it will break.  Also now your system can't compile C programs that want to use the `math.h` header.  Did you try the compile line I suggested?  It seems from your comment that the problem really is forcibly including header directories on the command line, and in the wrong order: when compiling C++ code you want the C++ version of math.h; when compiling C code the C version.  The compiler will handle this for you if you let it.

Comment: I understand how seriously is renaming system file. But I have already tried to compile another .cpp files witch uses math.h and cmath libraries and it's works perfectly. Please can you recommend how can I solve this problem without renaming ? Thanks

Comment: I said, you won't be able to compile _C_ code (that includes math.h).  `.cpp` files contain C++ code not C code.  You've basically removed the C math.h header so no C programs that compile with it will be able to find it and will fail to compile.  I've already described a better way to fix the problem in both my message and my comment above: do not add system headers to your compile line explicitly.  Let the compiler add them: it will ensure they are put into the proper order.  You haven't responded to either of my questions as to whether that worked or not.

Comment: I have changed my Makefile like you asked, and it's solved problem. Thanks

Comment: @MadScientist I get the same errors as the OP, but I use cmake. None of my projects compile anymore after the latest update of Xcode, however, everything worked well thus far. Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem? I reinstalled Xcode, which was a complete waste of time.

Comment: Sorry, but I support free software so I don't use MacOS, and I can't help you with Xcode problems.  If my comments above don't help solve your problem you can ask a new question in SO with details of the problem you're seeing, errors, etc. tagged with MacOS and/or Xcode and maybe a MacOS aficionado will help.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your packages :

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
```

With XCode updated, it could be fixed.

Comment: After upgrading the problem is still exists.